# dplyr filter for cells that contain only uppercase characters

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

If I have the following data frame:

```
    > testdf
  id test1      test2     test3      annot
1  A    10 0.96093147 0.9996099 A test 1 a
2  B    20 0.48922459 0.8225223 B-test-1-b
3  C    30 0.76671324 0.4031212    Ctest1c
4  D    40 0.92446136 0.7729842      ATEST
5  E    50 0.71542366 0.6379789     ATEST1
6  F    60 0.09695642 0.6293565     BTEST1
7  G    70 0.30056727 0.7030828     CTEST2
8  H    80 0.23391326 0.2112124     DTEST3
```

And I would like to filter using dplyr, alongside other method (like regex), to filter "annot" column to retain only the cells where **any characters present are upper-case** (numbers can be ignored for filtering purposes) to obtain the following:

```
> testdf
  id test1      test2     test3  annot
1  D    40 0.92446136 0.7729842  ATEST
2  E    50 0.71542366 0.6379789 ATEST1
3  F    60 0.09695642 0.6293565 BTEST1
4  G    70 0.30056727 0.7030828 CTEST2
5  H    80 0.23391326 0.2112124 DTEST3
```

I have tried several times but cannot get the combination right.

here is the data for this example data frame:

```
> dput(testdf)
structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), 
    test1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L), test2 = c(0.960931471, 
    0.489224595, 0.766713238, 0.924461365, 0.715423658, 0.096956416, 
    0.300567271, 0.23391326), test3 = c(0.999609908, 0.82252227, 
    0.403121205, 0.772984196, 0.637978895, 0.629356488, 0.703082753, 
    0.211212439), annot = c("A test 1 a", "B-test-1-b", "Ctest1c", 
    "ATEST", "ATEST1", "BTEST1", "CTEST2", "DTEST3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Are you having difficulties because _all_ of the elements of `annot` contain uppercase letters? The first character in the three entries you are trying to filter out is an uppercase letter.

Comment: Yes, I need to be able to filter for cells in which if there are any characters they are all uppercase. So need to be able to distinguish between cells that have some uppercase and cells that have only uppercase. @TTS answer seems to work for my purposes thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `dplyr` answer should suffice: filter `annot` for values that contain uppercase letters, but also don't contain lowercase letters. Numbers ignored, but this would also not include `annot` values that are all numbers.

```
new_df <- testdf %>%
  filter(str_detect(annot, '[:upper:]') & !str_detect(annot, '[:lower:]'))
```

```
  id test1      test2     test3  annot
1  D    40 0.92446136 0.7729842  ATEST
2  E    50 0.71542366 0.6379789 ATEST1
3  F    60 0.09695642 0.6293565 BTEST1
4  G    70 0.30056727 0.7030828 CTEST2
5  H    80 0.23391326 0.2112124 DTEST3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use base R's `grepl` as a logical test for strings containing a particular regex, and use that inside a `dplyr::filter`.

The regex for any uppercase letter is `"[[:upper:]]"`

```r
testdf %>% filter(grepl("[[:upper:]]", annot))
#>   id test1      test2     test3  annot
#> 1  D    40 0.92446136 0.7729842  ATEST
#> 2  E    50 0.71542366 0.6379789 ATEST1
#> 3  F    60 0.09695642 0.6293565 BTEST1
#> 4  G    70 0.30056727 0.7030828 CTEST2
#> 5  H    80 0.23391326 0.2112124 DTEST3
```

However, in your example, **all** the rows in `testdf` contain at least one uppercase letter (the first three cells have uppercase letters in the first position). So, to demonstrate, I have changed the first letter of each of the first three cells in `annot` to lowercase:

```
testdf <- structure(list(id = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), 
    test1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L), test2 = c(0.960931471, 
    0.489224595, 0.766713238, 0.924461365, 0.715423658, 0.096956416, 
    0.300567271, 0.23391326), test3 = c(0.999609908, 0.82252227, 
    0.403121205, 0.772984196, 0.637978895, 0.629356488, 0.703082753, 
    0.211212439), annot = c("a test 1 a", "b-test-1-b", "ctest1c", 
    "ATEST", "ATEST1", "BTEST1", "CTEST2", "DTEST3")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

testdf
#>   id test1      test2     test3      annot
#> 1  A    10 0.96093147 0.9996099 a test 1 a
#> 2  B    20 0.48922459 0.8225223 b-test-1-b
#> 3  C    30 0.76671324 0.4031212    ctest1c
#> 4  D    40 0.92446136 0.7729842      ATEST
#> 5  E    50 0.71542366 0.6379789     ATEST1
#> 6  F    60 0.09695642 0.6293565     BTEST1
#> 7  G    70 0.30056727 0.7030828     CTEST2
#> 8  H    80 0.23391326 0.2112124     DTEST3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using base R

```
df[!grepl("[a-z]", df$annot),]
# id test1      test2     test3  annot
# 4  D    40 0.92446136 0.7729842  ATEST
# 5  E    50 0.71542366 0.6379789 ATEST1
# 6  F    60 0.09695642 0.6293565 BTEST1
# 7  G    70 0.30056727 0.7030828 CTEST2
# 8  H    80 0.23391326 0.2112124 DTEST3
```